# Child element of tabs is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the [pen](http://codepen.io/mohammadhamza/pen/esKCD) I'm working on.
If you will see the pen,the first container have a child div that is not showing in the result.The Jquery as follows,

```
$('.content-canvas').find('div').hide();
$('.content-canvas div:first-child').show();
$('.tab-button span:first-child').addClass('active');
$('.tab-button').find('span').click(function(){
  $('.tab-button').find('span').removeClass('active');
  var currentclass=$(this).attr('class');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 $('.content-canvas').find('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class')==currentclass)
    {
      $('.content-canvas').find('div').hide();
      $(this).slideDown(200);
      $(this).children().show(200);
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line:

```
$('.content-canvas').find('div').hide();
```

Change to

```
$('.content-canvas > div').hide();
```

Do the same with all the same selectors you used. You only need to hide the `direct descendant`, not all `divs`.

Also, I recommend caching this selecotr into a variable:

```
var elements = $('.content-canvas > div').hide();
...
...
element.each(function() {
...
```

and so on, so that you don't have to jump into the DOM everytime.

Answer (score 1):

It's because at the beginning of your js code, you hide every div.
Show it by using something like:

```
$('.content-canvas .content1 div').show();
```

Or put your 'as' inside a span instead of a div such as:

```
<span>as</span>
```

Please check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/jHdta/10/)

Comment: @Mohammed Hâmzã does it fix your problem ?

Comment: Actaully it do not fix my problem,as I want a better solution.

Comment: Can you provide me any solution for Jquery

Comment: @Mohammed Hâmzã I added a fiddle example. I do it with javascript, I let your default html markup, I only add a 'content' class to do your each easier. Is this good ?